# Using a StreamBuilder and a SliverLists In CustomScrollView

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to use a `StreamBuilder` to fetch data and I want to display that data using a `SliverList` all inside a `CustomScrollView` so I can take advantage of the features that come with the `CustomScrollView`.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, it's easy, here you have a code sample:

```
    class SampleStreamBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
      Stream<List<String>> loadData() async* {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
        yield List.generate(10, (index) => "Index $index");
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: StreamBuilder<List<String>>(
            stream: loadData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return snapshot.hasData
                  ? CustomScrollView(
                      slivers: [
                        SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                            );
                          }, childCount: snapshot.data.length),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I had my Streambuilder inside of the CustomScrollView and later had errors that I didn't notice at first because I couldn't debug and had to use ```flutter run -d chrome --release```

Putting the ScrollView inside of the streambuilder fixed everything!

Comment: What if you dont want to rerender the whole CustomScrollView? How to make the StreamBuilder update just one Sliver?

Comment: SliverToBoxAdapter > StreamBuilder > Widget

Comment: it gives error if get data from firestore any idea?

Comment: if the data from firestore are snapshots you need to leave empty the datatype odf the StreamBuilder or change StreamBuilder<List<String>> to StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>.

Answer (score 9):

In this case it is fine to rerender the whole CustomScrollView. However if you want to rerender just one Sliver in a CustomScrollView, do it like this:

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
           return SliverToBoxAdapter(
             child: Text('sliver box'),
           );
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Remember to always return a Sliver inside the StreamBuilder.